# How to use "fmincon" to solve matrix minimization

Tags: matlab, matrix, optimization, minimization

**Question: How to use "fmincon" to solve the following minimization matrix problem?**

I am trying to find the f such that

a * ( b – ( inv(a) * inv(inv(a) + transpose(c)*inv(f)*c) * (inv(a)*d + transpose(c) * inv(f) * e)  ) )^2

is minimized subject to:

f > 0

**++++Variables:**

- a is (8x8) matrix which is known.
- b is (8x1) column vector which is known.
- c is (1x8) column vector which is known.
- d is (8x1) scalar which is known.
- e is (1x1) scalar which is known.
  and
- f is a scalar and is unknown.

Comment: What is your actual problem? Should you take the absolute value or not (code and problem statement are different)?

Comment: I do not agree with you that your problem should have two solutions due to the power of 2. `y = x^2 - 1` has only one minimum (at `x = 0`). I think you confused it with the zeros of this function (at `x=1` and `x=-1`).

Comment: Did you have a look at the [`fmincon` examples`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html#examples)?

Comment: @m7913d, the problem statement is correct. My problem is how to code this problem in the MatLab, and you're right. I removed the absolute value.

Comment: @m7913d Yes, I got your point. You are absolutely right about that. My problem should not return two solutions. I corrected it above, but I think it should return a (8x1) row vector of "V". Am I right? If so, how can I correct the code accordingly?

Comment: Before you are able to optimise your function, you should first check if you are able to evaluate your function (at the starting point). At the moment, your matrix dimensions do not agree.

Comment: Note that `V0` should have the same dimensions as the required result `V`. Your definition of `Aeq` and `beq` are wrong, please check the definition of those matrices in the `fmincon` manual, but you probably don't need them as you can use `ub` instead.

Comment: @m7913d Thank you for your inputs and insights! I followed your feedbacks. I changed the code accordingly. However, I still get one warning and the same error:

Warning: Length of upper bounds is < length(x);
filling in missing upper bounds with +Inf. 
> In checkbounds (line 47)
  In fmincon (line 307)
  In idzorek2 (line 28) 
----
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
Error in
idzorek2>@(V)(A*(E-(A*(A+B'*V*B)*(A*C+B'*V*D))).^2)
Error in idzorek2 (line 28)
V = fmincon(fun,V0,[],[],[],[],lb,ub)

I wonder if you give me some hints regarding this error.
Thanks, Matt!

Comment: `ub` should have the same dimensions as `lb` (and `V0`). You should check your matrix dimensions and/or your `fun` function. I do not know your formula, so you can try to localise the problem by evaluating parts of them and checking if the dimensions are as expected.

Comment: The dimensions of the above problem won't fit. Do you have the right dimensions?

Comment: @m7913d I corrected the code. The dimension of ub, lb and omega0 is the same, i.e. 8x1. I have posted my main formula. The formula comes from the Idzorek research paper (Black Litterman model) in page 26, formula 17 and formula 18 that you can find:

[linkhttps://faculty.fuqua.duke.edu/~charvey/Teaching/BA453_2006/Idzorek_onBL.pdf) _italic_ **bold** `research article of Idzorek`. 

Please note that I looked the dimensions, and to my little understanding, everything related to dimensions seems to be correct. I look forward on your insights. Thank you so far for your comments.

Comment: @Royi Yes the dimension seems to be correct in the function. Please note:
cov --> 8x8 and wk --> 8x1. ---------------Thefore:
function = (8x8) * (8x1 - remaining part)^2;-----------
Remaining part = ( inv(8x8) * inv(inv(8x8)+(8x1)*inv(1x1)*(1x8)) * (inv(8x8)*8x1+(8x1) * inv(1x1) * (1x1));--------- Remaining part = (inv(8x8) * inv(8x8) * (8x1) --------- Therefore, remaining part = 8x1 ------Now: function = (8x8) * ( (8x1) - (8x1) )^2 = 8x1 ----- Therefore the output of the function is 8x1.------- Moreover dimensions of ub, lb, and omega0 are 8x1. But I still get the above error in my output.

Comment: You should be consistent with your definition of `omega`. In your formula, it is a constant, but in your optimisation problem it is a vector. You should use your formula iteratively to calculate `w_k` for every element in `omega`. Note also that `fmincon` assumes a single function value, you probably want to minimise the norm of `w_k,% - w_k`.

Comment: @m7913d Please correct me if I am wrong. The output of function is 8x1. Therfore, when we take the first derivative w.r.t. omega, set the function to zero, and solve it for omega, we would have an omega of 8x1. And, the smallest positive value would be the solution to the minimization function. Is that what fmincon does, right?  Don't you think it is better to use lsqnonlin function for this problem? I have also written the code for Isqnonlin, but I get a value of 1 as my output.

Comment: Taking the first derivative is a simplified version of what `fmincon` does, because it has also to take the boundaries into account. One optimisation function will return you only one element of omega, i.e. `omega_k`. Indeed, you can use `lsqnonlin`.

Comment: @m7913d Thank you very much for your insights so far. It has really helped me. I still have some questions about lsqnonlin. ----Q1)) Writing my function in short format: [[a * (b -c)^2]]. Based on lsqnonlin, my function will already be raised to power 2. Thus, I need to write it in the following format: [[sqrt(a)*´(b-c)]]. Am I right? ----Q2)) Would the initial value have an effect on having a correct output? When I set the initial value=1, my output is 1. When I put initial value = 0.00005, then my output is 0.0000234564... .  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Q1) I do not understand were your `a` comes from. If you want to multiply it with `a` (NxN matrix) it may be easier to use `fmincon` and take the sum of the vector yourself.

Q2) `fmincon` or `lsqnonlin` gives you a local minimum, which may not be the global one. So, a different start value may result in a different result depending on the convexity of your function.

Comment: @m7913d Q1) a is 8x8 matrix. b and c are 8x1 matrices. The variable "omega" in which I am solving for it is within c and a scalar. But sticking back to Isqnonlin, to my little understanding, writing  my function as [[sqrt(a)*´(b-c)]] would be right since Isqnonlin is already raising it to power 2, correct? Q2), is there a function for finding global minimum?

Comment: If `a` is a matrix, I don't know if the sqrt is well defined. Global maximum is a really hard job, it is mostly done by trying different start values. I have never tried it with matlab, but I think some tools are available.

Comment: @m7913d Thank you very much for your comments. I really appreciate it. My code now works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the @m7913d, I solved the code via Isqnonlin:

```
clc;
clear all;

% random inputs A, B, C, D and E
a = rand(8,8)'*rand(8,8);
b = 2*rand(8,1) - 1;
c = 2*rand(1,8) - 1;
d = 2*rand(8,1) - 1;
e = 2*rand(1,1) - 1;

 % minimization term
 fun = @(f) a * ( b - ( inv(a) * inv(inv(a)+c'*inv(f)*c) * (inv(a)*d+c' * inv(f) * e)  ) );

f = lsqnonlin(fun,0.1,0,+inf)
```